# Compare two text files - spellchecking program in C

Tags: c, string, file-io, while-loop

I'm writing a spellchecking program that will compare a user's text file with a dictionary to see if the words they entered are in the dictionary. If not, an error message is printed to tell the user that the specific word is wrong. I've tried a number of variations of the code below but not getting the desired results. It's something in the nested while loop that's throwing it out. This code is in draft stage I have to make it more memory efficient etc and tidy it up. I'm just interested in getting it working first. Thanks!

EDIT: Have altered the code slightly as per the tips below. It now reads the first word and says that it is in the dictionary. It then displays the second word but the dictionary scanning loop doesn't run and the program hangs. I know its the nested while loop causing the issue I just can't get my head around it!

```
/*Spellcheck program*/
/*Author: */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
/*Open files and test that they open*/
FILE *fp1;
FILE *fp2;
char fname[20];
char wordcheck[45];/*The longest word in the English Language is 45 letters long*/
char worddict[45];
char dummy;
int i;
int dictcount = 0;

fp1 = fopen("dictionary.txt","r");

if (fp1 == NULL)
{
printf("The dictionary file did not open.");
exit(0);
}

printf("Please enter the path of the file you wish to check:\n");
scanf("%s", fname);
scanf("%c", &dummy);

fp2 = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (fp2 == NULL)
        {
        printf("Your file did not open, please check your filepath and try again.\n");

        printf("Please enter path of file you wish to check: \n");
        scanf("%20s",fname);

        fp2 = fopen(fname, "r");
        }

    else
        {
        printf("Your file opened correctly\n");
        }

/*When files are open, read each word from the text file into an array:*/

    while(fscanf(fp2,"%s", wordcheck)!=EOF)//Reads word from text file into array//
    {

        for (i=0; wordcheck[i]; i++)
        {
            wordcheck[i] = tolower(wordcheck[i]);//makes all characters lower case//
        }

        printf("%s", wordcheck);

        while(dictcount >= 0)//reads dictionary word into array//
        {   
            dictcount = 0;
            fscanf(fp1,"%s", worddict);

            if(strcmp(wordcheck, worddict)==0)//compare strings//
            {
            printf("This word: %s is in the dictionary\n", wordcheck);
            break;
            }

            else
            {
            dictcount++;
            }

            if(worddict == NULL)
            {
            printf("Your word: %s is not in the dictionary\n", wordcheck);
            }
        }
        dictcount++;
    }   
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't close. This guy has got talent.

Comment: Thanks for the input wildplasser. I get what you're saying re the function and not scanning until end of file but I have a break under the true strcmp. Would that not be enough to stop scanning to EOF?

Comment: Ah, I see. A good reason to move the second `strcmp()` block somewhere else.

Comment: I've just changed it to an else statement as you suggested below. I think if I can reset the dictionary loop I should be ok. I'm stuck with that. I need to set dictcount to 0 at the start of the loop correct and increment +1 each time the strcmp isn't true correct?

Comment: You did not (I see no change) Please look at the inner while(){} loop. Something will be printed *for every iteration*; I don't think that was your intention. ALSO: put an "\n" at the end of you printf()strings, otherwise they will not show up until the end_of_program.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of solving this is to first read the dictionary and build a hash table. You'd then read one word at a time from the input file and flag an error if the word doesn't exist on the hash table.

Comment: What's a hash table? I'm new to C we haven't covered that kind of thing yet. The format of my program should be similar to as it is in my code.

Comment: Hash table is not a C specific feature. Its a data-structure. Why is the format fixed?

Comment: Because we haven't covered data structures or anything like that yet. I'm new to C so this program should be C specific. Thanks for the input I'm not knocking your suggestion I just can't use it.

Comment: Well for a first-timer, your program is promising. Three hints 1) if you use `stdin` for the text file, you dont need to open that. 2) You don't need the second `if (strcmp(...)) {...}`, you could replace it by an `else {...}`, since it is the same test(but negated) and the words did not change. 3) You scan the dict in the inner loop, but forget to rewind it. It will still be positioned at the end-of-file at the time you enter the loop for the 2nd time. 4) oops I should have reacted under the OP

Comment: Also do a tolower of the worddict (unless its already guaranteed to be lowercase).

Comment: All of the dictionary words are lowercase. What's happening with me is this program is reading the first word from text file which is 'english'. It confirms that this word is in the dictionary but doesn't do anything else. It's not moving to the next word in the text file

Comment: Whe, once the word is found, there is no need to continue to scan the dictionary until EOF. BTW: Maybe you should put the lookup into a separate function?