# Refining Spell Checker C program

Tags: c, loops, file-io, binary-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare two text files - spellchecking program in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512261/compare-two-text-files-spellchecking-program-in-c)

I am making a spellcheck program and have an operational code that works but really needs refinement.

Problem 1: I only want to read alphanumeric characters into the wordcheck array before comparing the strings. I want to get rid of all special characters. I think isalphnum would be the best option but not sure how to implement it.

Problem 2: Program is very slow and wasting a lot of memory. I don't know how else to do it though. Could anyone give me some pointers? I'm lost with using binary functions and that's what I'm sure I should be doing! Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
/*Open files and test that they open*/
FILE *fp1;
FILE *fp2;
char fname[20];
char wordcheck[45];/*The longest word in the English Language is 45 letters long*/
char worddict[45];
char dummy;
int i;
int notfound;

fp1 = fopen("dictionary.txt","r");

if (fp1 == NULL)
{
printf("The dictionary file did not open.");
exit(0);
}

printf("Please enter the path of the file you wish to check:\n");
scanf("%s", fname);
scanf("%c", &dummy);

fp2 = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (fp2 == NULL)
        {
        printf("Your file did not open, please check your filepath and try again.\n");

        printf("Please enter path of file you wish to check: \n");
        scanf("%20s",fname);

        fp2 = fopen(fname, "r");
        }

    else
        {
        printf("Your file opened correctly\n");
        }

/*When files are open, read each word from the text file into an array:*/

    while(fscanf(fp2,"%s", wordcheck)!=EOF)//Reads word from text file into array//
    {

        for (i=0; wordcheck[i]; i++)
        {
            wordcheck[i] = tolower(wordcheck[i]);//makes all characters lower case//
        }
            fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_SET);

        /*printf("%s", wordcheck);//debugger*/

            while(fscanf(fp1,"%s", worddict)!=EOF)
            {   
                notfound = 1;

                if(strcmp(wordcheck, worddict)==0)//compare strings//
                {
                printf("This word: %s is in the dictionary\n", wordcheck);//debugger//
                notfound = 0;
                break;
                }
            }
            if(notfound == 1)
                {
                printf("%s is not in dictionary\n", wordcheck);
                }
    }
    printf("Your file has been checked. Please check any errors found");
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [A Spellchecker Used to Be a Major Feat of Software Engineering](http://prog21.dadgum.com/29.html)

Comment: Good article but I still want to use the best possible code for my program.

Comment: Yes, I've seen 2 different people as a total of 5 questions about this. Definitely homework.

Comment: Not homework. I'm learning C and was told that this is a popular challenge to give novice C programmers so that's why I'm doing it. Treat it as homework if you wish I'm not looking for an answer I need help that's all. It is a duplicate of that last post. Who's going to see it if I update it now? It's a week old!

Comment: Another dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580222/implementing-a-spellcheck-algorithm

Comment: "It is a duplicate of that last post. Who's going to see it if I update it now?" Don't post duplicates. EVER. If you update your old post, it will be bumped up again so people can see it.

Comment: Hire a smart chinese kid to do it for you of course!

Comment: @Bart sorry I didn't realise posts got bumped! I updated an old post before and I didn't see it move up the list that's why I assumed that. In that case mods feel free to delete this and apologies to all for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the dictionary once for each input word! If your input file is long then load the dictionary first into memory and then check each word in the file. If the dictionary is long you may need to store it into a hash table or a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Dictionary_representation). But even a simple array of dictionary words should give you an improved run time.